find the max value of array grid
Working on one problem, I've two arrays, they are like a grid with N cols with 2 rows
one = {3,4,6}
two = {6,5,4}

task is to travel from upper left corner to bottom right corner moving only right and down, so that max value over which you pass is as small as possible. Find the max value on the optimal path.
Output path is 3 > 4 > 5 > 4 and final output is 5
First Half Ends here


I thought that find the last occurrence of smallest element in first row, then from there take down to right corner, but its not correct.
Output I thought (3,6,5,4) > 6 but its wrong
Can anyone help me to understand this problem ?

Without seeing your code, it's pretty difficult to guess. But it seems clear, you are messing up your indices.

I'm not looking for a code, but understand the problem in right way, I guess I miss understood. Because I thought my answer is correct, but its not

I'm not claiming you are looking for a code, I'm merely stating you don't show the code you have that causes the problem.

Are you asking what the algorithm should be for solving the problem?

"I thought that find the last occurrence of smallest element in first row, then from there take down to right corner, but its not correct.": indeed, that is not correct. So it seems you have spotted what you did wrong already. "Can anyone help me to understand this problem?": it looks like you already understand the problem, and that you have come up with the wrong approach. What is your question?

you can go both right and down -> from the first, going right and then down encounters lesser values than 6, so don't go to 6. But it would need knowledge of the entire grid before moving (if the grid were to be bigger than this)

updated question, first half is the real problem statement, second half is what I understood

@Stultuske, grid size is mentioned in first line

"...so that max value over which you pass is as small as possible...", so you need to minimize the max value you encountered in the path. If the max values for different paths are 5 and 6, respectively, for example, then you should select the path with 5

@Maria N cols isn't really a fixed value. anyway, in your example, you have the option to go to 4 or 6. your goal is to pick the smallest possible. So ... why do you think 6 is smaller than 4?

You need to ask your teacher if the task is unclear ..

This is 2d Dynamic Programming problem. See here.

@user24714692
, can you please share the ask in this problem in some lame way, I'm not able to get the problem fully ?

@Maria You always have two choices for each move. Right or down. This is where you realize it's a dynamic programming problem. You try to solve the smaller problem, record the result, and move forward. Here, we initialize a grid to "memoize" our subproblems' records. In each move, pick the smaller one of these two Math.max(dp[i - 1][j], G[i][j]) < Math.max(dp[i][j - 1], G[i][j]), as your two choices from previous row and previous col, and compare it with the current cell. Save the max. Then, move to next option. Do the same comparison.

@Maria You only need to print this line of code Math.max(dp[i - 1][j], G[i][j]) < Math.max(dp[i][j - 1], G[i][j]) in each iteration and you'll understand the solution.
